# Windows store Window with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm not sure if I've chosen a proper title for this question or not. Anyway I'm developing a WPF application and I need to know whether there are any approach to simulate a windows store Window in WPF application or not?

To be clear I should say in window store apps you can access the open apps by moving the mouse cursor to the top-left corner of the screen. This is also possible in WPF apps only if the WindowState is not Maximized. If you set the WindowState to Maximized you don't have any access to anywhere else except your own application.

Please let me know if I haven't explained this issue clearly. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.